# Extension or any method to override the registration module in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, registration, magento-1.9

I am working on custom registration module. Thus, installed a registration  extension from `magento` commerce. But that extension is crashed and after un-install also its giving errors.

So is there any way or extension or any procedure so that I will get my default `magento` registration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below extension...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html

It's strange because same module I used and its work fine. Anyways you can uninstall it from **Magento Connect Manager** or do manually by deleting below things.

**Remove below directories and files:-**

app/code/community/Amar
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/profile.xml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/profile
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/profile.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/profile
app/etc/modules/Amar_Profile.xml
js/profile

**And delete below entry from core_resource table**

profile_setup

**Note:-** If you cache enabled then please refresh it.

Comment: I have used the same extension and everything in registration module got crashed. Do you have any idea how do I remove/ delete it completely. @parag

Comment: And please remove maintenance flag from root if created.